# Create a contract renewal summary table

Tags: dax, summary, contract

I have a Contract table that includes the following columns:

| ID | Account | Service | Start Date | End Date | Amount ($) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Account A | Service 1 | 2021/05/18 | 2022/05/17 | $100,000 |
| 2 | Account A | Service 1 | 2022/05/18 | 2023/05/17 | $105,000 |
| 3 | Account B | Service 1 | 2021/04/13 | 2022/04/12 | $80,000 |
| 4 | Account B | Service 2 | 2022/09/15 | 2022/09/14 | $50,000 |

Consider for this question, today's date is 2022/06/04 (June 4th, 2022). I'd like to create a new table using DAX that summarizes, for each Account and Service, the following:

- Service renewal: the latest contract for each unique Account+Service has an End Date greater than today's date AND a previous contract for the same Account+Service exists whose End Date is within 1 day of the latest contract Start Date.
- New Service sale: the latest contract for each unique Account+Service has an End Date greater than today's date AND no previous contract exists for the same Account+Service whose End Date is within 1 day of the latest contract Start Date. The Service is still considered new if the Account had purchased the same Service in a previous year.
- Service cancellation: the latest contract for each unique Account+Service has an End Date less than today's date.

The new table could look like this (using data from the original Contracts table above):

| Account | Service | Action | Most Recent Contract ID | Renewal Rate (%) |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Account A | Service 1 | Renew | 2 | 105% |  |
| Account B | Service 1 | Cancel | 3 | null |  |
| Account B | Service 2 | New | 4 | null |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

In the new table (above) I'd like:

- Action = Renew, Cancel or New based on the previously explained options
- Renewal Rate = Active contract amount (whose End Date > Today's Date) / Previous adjacent contract amount
- Most Recent Contract ID = contract ID of the most recent instance of the contract matching the Account+Service pair (even if the most recent contract was canceled whose End Date < Today's Date).

Comment: Can you explain why `Account B` and `Service 2` are considered `New`? Also why do some start dates seem to be after the end dates?

Comment: I'm sorry @AngeloCanepa, I edited the first table so that it's considered New. I.e., its a contract that doesn't have a previous contract adjacent to it. (The new table shows Account B and Service 2 starting and ending in September now.)

Comment: It would be preferable to solve this by adding an "Action" column in the originating Contracts table so I can add slicers, or use Action in the x-axis of a bar chart visual.